# How to model 0/1 data?

Tags: model

I have all in all 600 measurements: 20 subjects x 15 different stimuli x 2 ears (presented in each ear separately). I use 4 different methods to detect whether there is a significant response in each measurement. The output of each method is either 0 (not significant) or 1 (significant). I need to test which method gives me the most number of significant detections. I also use different amount of data (10-20-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100 % of the measurement time) for each method to find out how fast the methods can detect the significant response, i.e. which method is more effective.

I am not interested how the methods perform for each individual stimulus, but how they perform in general.

Please help me to find the correct model to compare the methods!

Best regards Anna

I tried glm (output ~ Method + NrEpochs + Method:NrEpochs, family=binomial(link = 'logit'), data = D), but the model failed at homogeneity test.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct site for your questions. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. Maybe [datascience.se]? If not, click the hamburger icon in the top right of this window and find a site that fits.